# RT3090 random disconnects on wifi?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, ralink

OK well I got my card to connect and all that but now it absolutely refuses to hold the connection for more than a minute or so and will not reconnect unless I reboot the system. I have a syslog here if anyone needs it http://paste.ubuntu.com/675271/

Answer (score 1):

Try *installing the deb* from [this link](http://www.halibutdepot.org/how_to_build_rt3090_for_ubuntu_lucid/).

..note the instructions at the bottom, in case you switch kernels to a different kernel -- e.g., from linux-generic to linux-server.  Upgrades of the same kernel type should be handled automatically.

You *may* also need to disable the old driver by doing the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/myblacklist.conf
```

..and enter the following lines:

```
#blacklisting the old wireless drivers
blacklist rt2800pci
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have open source driver you should try with proprietary one using Markus Heberling PPA, you need to properly blacklist open source driver before you install proprietary one:

http://www.techytalk.info/ralink-rt3090-ubuntu-driver-ppa/

Proprietary works better for most people including me because it is more mature. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately that's precisely what I've done to even get it to use the wireless card and pick up other networks and it still drops out after a minute or so.